# Differences between row 11 or 12 in Airbus A320?

Tags: air-travel, seating, airbus

The rows 11 and 12 of the Airbus A320 look very much alike. I've been sitting on row 11 before I think and I couldn't see much difference between them.

Are there any differences between row 11 and row 12 in the Airbus A320?

Some examples:

- Row 11 might lack reclining functionality because row 12 is also an exit row.
- There could be a difference in leg room.
- Direct overhead storage could be missing.

[image: Wing exit rows in Airbus A320]

Comment: There are MANY different versions of the A320.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Row 11 has extra legroom because it's in an exit row, but it is very likely that Row 11 seats will not recline, as doing so would impinge the room in the exit row behind.

If you know the Airline and flight number, you can enter that information in [seatguru.com](http://seatguru.com), which will display comments about each seat on the aircraft.

Comment: Yup, so row 12 seems better. I guess it also has extra leg room.

Comment: Note that in many aircraft (especially short-haul and LCCs), none of the seats recline. Also note that numbering may not be consistent from one airline to another.

Comment: Seatguru.com is your friend.